# Disposing by setting to null?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I'm aware of technique to handle IDisposable in a traditional manner. Say, in OnStop() method of windows service I close message queue client:

```
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Dispose();
        }
```

For the first time today I saw one guy doing that this way:

```
        using (client)
        {
            client = null;
        }
```

What is exactly happening inside his "using" or does he dispose correctly at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `using`-based colleague's code will work, but is arguably overkill;

```
using(client) {
    client = null;
}
```

is essentially:

```
{ // scope here to denote that 'tmp' is not defined outside this scope
  var tmp = client;
  try {
      client = null;
  } finally {
      if(tmp != null) tmp.Dispose();
  }
}
```

(not *quite* that in all cases, as there are value-types and explicit interface implementation to think about).

Personally, I'd just use `using` for the whole thing where possible (i.e. in the code that initially allocates client).

One time I might use this is a lazy:

```
using(client as IDisposable) { client = null; } // dispose if needed
```

i.e. `client` is something outside my control, and I'm not sure if it implements `IDisposable` or not, but if it does, I need to release it.

Comment: BTW, one thing I think would enhance the usability of "using" would be the ability to explicitly set the "shadow variable" to null, so that the object wouldn't be disposed, or else have a version of "using" which would only dispose in case of fault.  A constructor, for example, could then "using" the fields of the object to be constructed, and then decide to "keep" them just before it returned.  It's possible to use try/finally blocks instead of "using", but they're more verbose and less clear.

Comment: @supercat IMO that scenario is already pretty complex - better to be explicit about it, and understand what is going on (i.e. I'm happy with `try`/`finally` there)

Comment: I just looked at the code again and think I figured out the purpose--if "client" is a field or property, its lifetime could probably not be confined to a "using" block.  In some cases, it may be necessary to clear out a field or property holding a reference to the object before calling Dispose upon it.  The "using" code shown here would be more concise than explicitly creating a temporary variable, though an even better approach would be to use a "Zap" routine for such a purpose.

Answer (score 6):

The `using(){}` statement grabs a copy of the reference var so this assignment with `null` is ineffective.

Comment: but also harmless (it doesn't interfere with the call to dispose)

Comment: Agree in second case you must copy pointer once more.
It makes no sense to make Dispose implicit inside dispose itself.
In any case you also need a null check to avoid null ref exception when reentering dispose.

Comment: @Martijn - harmless? usually but not if you wanted to postpone the Dispose of `client`. Rare but possible.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Not terribly rare--such postponement would be a very nice pattern in constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Exiting from

```
using (client)
{
}
```

`client.Dispose()` is called automatically for you.
`client = null` should be called out of that code in my opinion.
Remember that to use `using(object)` the object should implement `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: Why downvote? It I told something wrong, please explain so I can correct or delete my answer...

Comment: No, there's nothing particularly wrong; there were a few odd downvotes cast by a single user; no strong tie to any users involved in this thread. Just... odd, really.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks not effective at all. Since the client is set to null the using has nothing referenced to dispose anymore, even though the actual object is still in memory, just not referenced by any variable (it will be garbage collected later on, but what's the point of the using then?).

Answer (score 0):

If the scope of "client" extends outside the "using" block, as it would appear to, the code as written will ensure that "client" gets disposed before control leaves the "using" block, and the reference to the newly-defunct "client" object will be destroyed.  Nulling out the reference to it may be important if it's a field, and may be critical if it's a property that attaches events.

My guess would be that "client" is a field or property, and that the author of the "using" code thought it was more concise than the version given by Marc Gravell.  I would grant the author that the code is concise, but would suggest that even more concise and clearer would be to define a generic "Zap" routine which accepts an IDisposable *by reference*, uses Interlocked.Exchange to read and null it, and disposes it if it wasn't null.  In that case, the "using" statement would be replaced with:

```
  Zap(ref client);
```

which has the benefit of being more concise while almost certainly being clearer.